# Непонятная конструкция в PHP

Tags: php

Есть следующий код:

```
class MoySklad
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $base = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/';
    protected $requestTime = 60;

    public function __construct($login, $password)
    {
        $this->auth = base64_encode($login.':'.$password);
    }

    public function request($url, $data = array())
    {
        if (strpos($url, 'http') !== 0) {
            $url = $this->base . rtrim($url, '/');
        }

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic '.$this->auth,
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $this->requestTime);

        if ($data) {
            $data($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, true);
        }

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
        return $data;
    }  
}
```

Непонятна часть `$data($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);` в request. Что значит эта конструкция, учитывая что `$data` изначально массив. И переменная `$post` нигде не объявляется.

Comment: вместо $post должна быть $data. Смысл этой строчки отправить массив методом POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь ошибка. Вместо `$post` должно быть `$data`. Кроме того опечатка еще и в этой строке

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, true);
```

Должно быть

```
if (!empty($data)) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
}
```

Comment: То есть $data($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data)? Все равно конструкция странная. Разве бывает так, чтобы '$переменная()'?

Comment: Бывает. Но тут тоже ошибка :) Сейчас покажу исправленный вариант

Comment: Спасибо, помогло :)